# Integrable functions (domain)

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

"Verify if both of this functions are integrable in their domains:
$g(x) = ( \|x\|^2 + 1)^{  -\frac{a}{2} }, \forall a>n$, domain in $ \mathbb{R} ^n$

$h(x) = \|x\|^{-\|x\|}$, defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$"

I can't work this out. I believe I have to prove that there exists a majorant in the integral of the functions but I don't know how. Thank you.

Comment: What is this $b$?

Comment: @zhw sorry, my mistake. It is now corrected

Comment: Can you do this problem for $n=1$?

Comment: But h does not depend on n. Do I make x= 1?

Comment: $h$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$ is it not?

Comment: @zhw.: No, on $\Bbb R ^3$, but could have been on $\Bbb R ^n$.

Comment: I'm trying to say something simple: The function $|x|^{-|x|}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}.$ I think it is good to try the one-dimensional cases first for both of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: $g(x) = \frac 1 {(\|x\|^2 + 1)^{\frac a 2}}$. On $\bar B (0,1)$ (the closed ball centered in $0$ and radius $1$, which is compact) $g$ is continuous, therefore it is bounded, therefore integrable. Outside of this ball, i.e. when $\|x\| > 1$ we have $g(x) \le \frac 1 {(\|x\|^2) ^{\frac a 2}} = \frac 1 {\|x\|^a}$, which is known to be integrable for $a>n$. So, $g$ is integrable both on $\|x\| \le 1$ and on $\|x\| > 1$, therefore it is integrable on the whole space (provided $n>1$).

For the second one: again, split the whole space into $\bar B (0,n+1)$ and its complementary. On the complementary, $\|x\|>n$, therefore $\frac 1 {\|x\| ^{\|x\|}} \le \frac 1 {\|x\| ^{n+1}}$ and $\frac 1 {\|x\| ^{n+1}}$ is integrable here. Let us see what happens on $\bar B (0,n+1)$ (which is compact): $h$ is continuous, the only problems arise in $0$. But $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac 1 {\|x\| ^{\|x\|}} = \lim \limits _{r \to 0^+} \frac 1 {r^r} = \lim \limits _{r \to 0^+} \Bbb e ^{- r \log r} = \Bbb e ^{- \lim \limits _{r \to 0^+} r \log r} = 1$, so in reality $h$ is bounded on $\bar B (0,n+1)$ and can be extended to a continuous function on it, therefore it is integrable.

We have used that on $\bar B (0,r)$ the function $\frac 1 {\|x\|^p}$ is integrable if and only if $p>n$, for all $r>0$.

Comment: No, the dimension $n$ is important here. For example, $1/|x|^2$ is not integrable over $\{|x|>1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n > 1.$ (For $n=2$ you can verify this using polar coordinates.)

Comment: @zhw.: Thank you, my mind was in $\Bbb R$, where I usually answer these questions. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a homemade argument for the first one. Let $V_n$ denote volume measure on $\mathbb {R}^n.$ We'll be done if we show

$$\int_{\{|x|>1\}}\frac{1}{|x|^a}\, dV_n<\infty.$$

Write the above as

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \int_{\{m\le |x|<m+1\}}\frac{1}{|x|^a}\, dV_n.$$

Recall that $V_n(rB) = r^nV_n(B)$ for $r>0,$ where $B$ is the unit ball. Thus the last sum is bounded above by

$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^a}[V_n((m+1)B) - V_n(mB)] = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^a}V_n(B)((m+1)^n - m^n).$$

You can verify that $(m+1)^n-m^n \le Cm^{n-1},$ where $C$ is a constant independent of $m.$ So everything is good if

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{a-(n-1)}}<\infty.$$

Since $a-(n-1) > 1,$ we're done.